# Differences in arrow function and no arrow function in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I am currently very confused about when should we use arrow function and when we should not. I did the search about this but still I'm not clear. For example, I create a button to count clicks, the code is like below:

```
 class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {counter: 0};
  }
  buttonPressedIncrease = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {counter: prevState.counter + 1}
    });
  }
  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Counter: {this.state.counter}</div>
        <button onClick={this.buttonPressedIncrease}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I use arrow function on the button like this: **onClick={() => this.buttonPressedIncrease}**, the function does not work like I use in the code above.

Anyone can explain for me this problem? When will arrow function work and when will it not?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Change it to`() => this.buttonPressedIncrease()` and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, event listeners such as `onClick` expect to be given a **reference** to the function you want to invoke.

With this in mind:

```
onClick={this.buttonPressedIncrease}
```

is correct because `this.buttonPressedIncrease` is a reference to a function and it is the one you want to run.

---

However,

```
onClick={() => this.buttonPressedIncrease}
```

is incorrect because while `() => this.buttonPressedIncrease` is a function reference, it is not the function you want to execute. You don't want to execute the anonymous function `() => this.buttonPressedIncrease`, you want to execute `this.buttonPressedIncrease`. Remember that functions are only invoked with `()`. Ignoring the parenthesis only returns their reference. That's why this won't work -  the anonymous function doesn't invoke the wanted function.

---

Though, if you want, you could do:

```
onClick={() => this.buttonPressedIncrease()}
```

because the anonymous function will invoke the wanted function. Though I'd stick to the former solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have already defined `buttonPressedIncrease` as a "fat-arrow" function:

```
buttonPressedIncrease = () => {
```

This means that if you write `() => this.buttonPressedIncrease`, you are passing an anonymous function that returns the function. `onClick` wants a function that *does something*, not a function that returns another function.

Since you are using a fat arrow when you define the function, `this` is already bound correctly, so you should just pass the name of the function:

```
onClick={this.buttonPressedIncrease}
```

---

Sometimes in JSX you see `onClick={() => someFunction()}` (note that `someFunction()` is being *called*, unlike in your example), which may be the source of your confusion. This is another way to keep the right `this` in scope but comes at the cost of creating a new function every time your `render` method is called. For this reason, the above approach is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that arrow function is just a different syntax of the traditional javascript function(pseudo code):

```
function funcName(arg1,arg2) {
  return returned_exp/value
}
```

Arrow representation

```
const funcName = (arg1,arg2) => returned_exp/value
```

**Now, note that the returned expression can be a function here.**

So in your code

```
<button onClick={this.onClickHandler}></button>
```

you just pass a function that needs to be executed onClick. Where as in below code

```
<button onClick={() => this.onClickHandler()}></button>
```

you pass a function which, when executed executes the function this.onClickHandler ( a set of open and closed parenthesis calls a function). 
So generally we use the latter approach when we need to pass some data/object/function to the onClickHandler as arguments like so:

```
<button onClick={() => this.onClickHandler(this.props.requiredStuff)}></button>
```

Hope this helps !